# Create <div> foreach Address in a List<Address> in the properties of a List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Here's my problem:

I have a List that I get from an API call.

I'm making a card for each item BUT in the structure of the itens one of the properties is a List<Address'>.
I can build the cards with the following code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" style=" width: 100%;">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div runat="server" class="card" style=" width: 100%;">
            <div class="card-body"  >
            <h3 class="card-title"><%#Eval("Name")%></h3>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">DoesntMatter:<%# Eval("DoesntMatter") %></h6>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">DoesntMatter2:<%# Eval("DoesntMatter2") %> </h6>
            <p class="card-text"><%#Eval("BairrosExibicao")%></p>
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<%#Eval("PKOfSomething") %>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                More info ...
            </button>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="<%#Eval("PKOfSomething") %>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        
                        // HERE I NEED TO CREATE A <DIV> FOR EACH ADDRESS IN EACH ITEM AND GET THE INFO OF EACH ADDRESS

                    </ItemTemplate>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

The DataSource is being binded in the code behind.

Please help

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 2 ItemTemplates, replace the second one with a Repeater with your Address fields.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>Addresses:<br /></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            StreetName: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StreetName") %>
            <br />
            City: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "City") %>
            <br />
            PostalCode: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PostalCode") %>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Add `OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound"` event to the DataList and try something like this:

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
         e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater rpter = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("Repeater1");
        if (rpter != null)
        {
            // Assumes the main object is called 'Card'.
            Card card = (Card)e.Item.DataItem;

            // And assumes the Card has a property called Addresses.
            rpter.DataSource = card.Addresses;
            rpter.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```